# Pagination not working when loadonce is set to true

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, free-jqgrid

I have around 50 records and I want only 10 rows to be displayed per page in the jqgrid.If I set rowNum:10 it only displays 10 records with loadOnce:true.I want client side column searching to be implemented so I used loadonce property.I know that with loadonce:true only number records specified in rowNum property are fetched.

Thank you.

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({

  url:"<%=url%>ObjectController?module="+module+"&levelId="+levelId+"&subLevelId="+subLevelId+"&subSubLevelId="+subSubLevelId+"&docRefNo="+docRefNo+"&divisionId="+divisionId+"&deptId="+deptId+"&viewDocStatus="+viewDocStatus+"&docStatus="+docStatus+"&queryString="+queryString+"&qString="+qString+"&V="+plantId+"&searchString="+searchString,
  datatype: "json",
  rowNum:10,
  rowList : PAGINATIONPAGESIZES,
  paging: true, 
  autowidth: true,
  altRows:false,
  rownumbers: true,
  multiselect: true,
  shrinkToFit: false,
  viewrecords: true,
  loadonce:true,
  ignoreCase:true, 
  multiboxonly: false,
  loadComplete : function () {
    jQuery("#grid").setGridParam({rowNum:10}).trigger("reloadGrid");
  },
  beforeSelectRow: handleMultiSelect,

  <% if(workFlowCreatorRoleList != null 
        && workFlowCreatorRoleList.size() >0 
        && workFlowCreatorRoleList.contains(Integer.valueOf(roleId)) 
        || (session.getAttribute("employeeRoleId")!=null 
        && session.getAttribute("employeeRoleId").toString().equalsIgnoreCase(com.sobis.ims.util.ApplicationConstants.GLOBAL_ADMIN_ROLE))) { %>
    colNames: ["","docId","","I","","","R","Document No","Title","Issue No","Rev No","Issue Effective Date","","","",""],
  <% } else { %>
    colNames: ["","docId","","Document No","Title","Issue No","Rev No","Issue Effective Date","","","",""],
  <% } %>

  colModel: [{
    name: 'viewURL',
    search:true,
    hidden:true,
    width:0,
    fontsize:'5px',
    resizable: true, 
    title :false,
    classes:"grid-col",
    },{
```

Answer (score 1):

rowNum parameter shows the number of records specified, while loadonce load all the data. By example if your response have 50 records with rowNum = 10 and loadonce is set to true, then all the 50 records are loaded locally, but in grid are displayed only the first 10. If you set to use a pager, then you can use it to view the rest of records.

I highly recommend you to read the docs depending on the jqGrid version used - Guriddo jqGrid or free-jqGrid.